# Is a trailing ampersand legal in a URL?

Tags: http, url, uri, specifications

A URL like

```
http://localhost/path?a=b&c=d
```

is fine - but what is the status of the same URL with a trailing ampersand?

```
http://localhost/path?a=b&c=d&
```

For example the Java Servlet API allows it where [Scala's Spray](https://github.com/spray/spray/wiki) does not (ie it throws an error).

I've tried to find the answer in the [URI syntax spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986), but not sure how to parse their grammar.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The URI syntax spec is for generic URIs. It allows anything in the [query](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4). I am not aware of any specification which actually specifies ampersand-separated key=value pairs. I believe it is merely convention. I know that PHP, for example, offers an option for using a different separator. But now, everyone uses ampersand-separated things when they want key-value pairs. You still occasionally come across things which use it for just a simple string, e.g. http://example.com/?example. This is perfectly valid.

The basic answer, though, is that `&` is valid anywhere in the query string, including at the end.

---

*Demistifying the RFC syntax*, or *Why `&` is valid anywhere in the query string:*

First, you have

```
query       = *( pchar / "/" / "?" )
```

(So a query string is made of any number of `pchar` and literal slashes and question marks.)

Going back, you have

```
pchar         = unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / ":" / "@"
```

And earlier still

```
sub-delims  = "!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")"
            / "*" / "+" / "," / ";" / "="
```

So a literal `&` is in `sub-delims` which is in `pchar`, so it's valid in `query`

Comment: It's worth noting [section 1.3](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-1.3) of that spec which forwards users to [rfc2234](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2234) where ABNF is formalized.  Yes the grammar takes some getting used to, but it's not that bad once you understand where the references are.

Answer (score 9):

I think there is an unwritten rule that all RFCs must be near impossible to understand. You're not the first person unable to parse the grammar and - in my humble opinion - Spray also failed too.

There is nothing wrong with a trailing ampersand. It is a legal character in the URI used to separate parameters. A trailing ampersand may be pointless, but it isn't invalid. Spray should (again, only in my opinion) be simply ignoring it.

Comment: No, they **shall** be near impossible to understand. =D

Answer (score 0):

If you have a url like the following in a plain-text email:

Please follow this link `https://server/doc?param=test.` to reset the password of your account.

It becomes a useful feature since if the last parameter ends with ". " (dot + space) and is placed in an e-mail, all kinds of mail clients assume that the dot is ending a sentence and exclude it from the clickable link they add if they detect a URL.

Putting the link between double-quotes or angle-brackets isn't supported in all mail clients and default URL encoding leaves the dot as it is not a reserved URI character...

I ended up appending a trailing ampersand "&" to the URL to fix this, call me crazy but it works.