# Symbol & at end of queryString without putting it

Tags: ios, cordova, rest

I´m developing an app. On the server side I implemented a RestfulWebService. On the client side, I´m using a phonegap and the plugin cordovaHTTP for my HTTPS requests in iOS clients. I got a strange issue, in every request I made using the cordovaHttp plugin I'm getting a '&' at the end of the query string.
I made debug on client side, but found nothing. I also noticed that when data came to server side this symbol is already there. 
What could be the problem?

Comment: Is there an actual problem with the trailing ampersand, or are you just wondering? [`&` is valid anywhere in the query string, including at the end](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6663362/is-a-trailing-ampersand-legal-in-a-url)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. The cordovaHTTP plugin build the queryString from the URL base and the parameters sent. I'm passing the queryString already constructed on the url and (empty parameters), so the plugin completes it with an ampersand at the end.