# Inserting a parameter in a URL query string if not already present with pure regular expression substitution

Tags: regex, query-string

I want to add a param with `&show_pinned_search=1` or `?show_pinned_search=1` on my ur string if it does not already exist. I'm able to add the parameter `show_pinned_search=1` if it not already existing using **negative lookahed** approach like `(?!show_pinned_search=1)` but having difficulties deciding to preceding character is `&` or `?`. Testing demo: https://regex101.com/r/aNccK6/1

**Example Input:**

```
https://www.example.com/property/villa-alexia/BC-1414?tes=dfgdf&fcb=5&show_pinned_search=1
http://www.example.com/property/hyat-doral/HA-4509801?show_pinned_search=1
https://www.example.com/property/villa-alexia/BC-1414?tes=dfgdf&fcb=5
http://www.example.com/property/hyat-doral/HA-4509801
http://www.example.com/property/hyat-doral/HA-4509801?show_pinned_search=1
https://www.example.com/property/villa-alexia/BC-1414?tes=dfgdf&fcb=5
```

**Expected Output:**

```
https://www.example.com/property/villa-alexia/BC-1414?tes=dfgdf&fcb=5&show_pinned_search=1
http://www.example.com/property/hyat-doral/HA-4509801?show_pinned_search=1
https://www.example.com/property/villa-alexia/BC-1414?tes=dfgdf&fcb=5&show_pinned_search=1
http://www.example.com/property/hyat-doral/HA-4509801?show_pinned_search=1
http://www.example.com/property/hyat-doral/HA-4509801?show_pinned_search=1
https://www.example.com/property/villa-alexia/BC-1414?tes=dfgdf&fcb=5&show_pinned_search=1
```

Comment: what language you're using?

Comment: actually I need in pure regex, if it was language then I can do it without regex

Comment: you can't use regex to manipulate your string. regex is only for lookup and extraction.

Comment: is it possible to do it here on regex101.com, have a look on testing demo: https://regex101.com/r/aNccK6/1

Comment: Regex don't do replace, they just match. Replace can be done *via* language or tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regexp checks if you have or not to insert a `show_pinned_search=1` entry:

```
^([^?]+)(?:\??)(?!(?:.*)&?show_pinned_search=1(?:&.*)?$)(.*)$
```

Step by step:

- **`([^?]+)(?:\??)`**:match the first part of the url to the question mark `?` if any. Only the part before the possible question mark is captured (group id **`$1`**).
- **`(?!(?:.*)&?show_pinned_search=1(?:&.*)?$)`**: look ahead to ensure there are no occurences of `show_pinned_search=1` in the leading part of the url
- **`(.*)`**: retrieve the leading part (which has no `show_pinned_search=1` occurrences of course) and capture it (group id **`$2`**).

Then proceed to this substitution:

```
$1?show_pinned_search=1&$2
```

The trick here is to insert `show_pinned_search=1` **right after the question mark**, so you don't have to bother if there is a question mark or an ampersand `&` before.

A minor disadvantage here is that you can get a leading ampersand in your string if the url doesn't end have a parameter leading part or ends with a question mark. However, [it's not a big deal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6663585/4375327).

[Working Regexp101.com fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/TMiRth/2).

Comment: but it still have one issue see here https://regex101.com/r/aNccK6/3 adding `?show_pinned_search=1&` an extra `&` later

Comment: @SarahRiddell Yes, that's what I said in the paragraph beginning with "A minor disadvantage". A link points to an answer explaining it should not be a problem. Or maybe I misunderstood your comment?

Answer (score 0):

**This one of the way of doing it**

Here the idea is first to check if the test string includes the pattern we are testing for. if it does than we don't change anything if not than we search for the last index of `&` and `?`. whichever index is higher we add that special character along with `show_pinned_search=1`

```js
let arr = [`https://www.example.com/property/villa-alexia/BC-1414?tes=dfgdf&fcb=5&show_pinned_search=1`,

`http://www.example.com/property/hyat-doral/HA-4509801?show_pinned_search=1`,

`https://www.example.com/property/villa-alexia/BC-1414?tes=dfgdf&fcb=5`,

`http://www.example.com/property/hyat-doral/HA-4509801`,

`http://www.example.com/property/hyat-doral/HA-4509801?show_pinned_search=1`,

`https://www.example.com/property/villa-alexia/BC-1414?tes=dfgdf&fcb=5`,
];

let op = arr.map(e=>{
  let temp = e.match(/(\?|&)show_pinned_search=1/); 
  let ampIndex = e.lastIndexOf('&');
  let quesIndex = e.lastIndexOf('?');
  if(temp) return e;
  else return ampIndex > quesIndex ? e+'&show_pinned_search=1' : e+`?show_pinned_search=1`
})

console.log(op);
```

Comment: Op asked a pure regexp solution.

Comment: exactly @Amessihel I can do it myself for js,php or python and so on, but I need on pure regex

Comment: Thanks for your effort